# PHP Add more value to foreach for display group by vendor

Tags: php, mysql

How do I add more value to this code for display?

**Ex :** I added 5 products to cart with different vendors.

```
P1 from vendor name TEST1
P2 and P3 from vendor name TEST2
P4 from vendor name TEST3
P5 from vendor name TEST4
```

**MY CODE :**

```
function getVendors()
{
  foreach($_SESSION["products"] as $product) {
    $org[$product["member_display_name"]][]   =   $product["p_name"];
  }
  return (!empty($org)) ? $org : array();
}

foreach (getVendors() as $vendor => $prods) {
  echo "<li>Vendor Name : {$vendor} </li>";
  echo "<li>" . implode("</li><li>",$prods) . "</li>";
}
```

This code given output like:

```
Vendor Name : TEST1
P1
Vendor Name : TEST2
P2
P3
Vendor Name : TEST3
P4
Vendor Name : TEST4
P5
```

**This is what I want**

I want to add `$product["member_payment"]` for display like this :

```
Vendor Name : TEST1
P1
Payment to Vendor : 000-111-111
Vendor Name : TEST2
P2
P3
Payment to Vendor : 000-111-222
Vendor Name : TEST3
P4
Payment to Vendor : 000-111-333
Vendor Name : TEST4
P5
Payment to Vendor : 000-111-444
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you need to restructure your array a bit. Add an extra pair of keys inside $org, so you can access it from iterator

```
function getVendors() {
    foreach($_SESSION["products"] as $product) {
        $org[$product["member_display_name"]]['product'][]   =   $product["p_name"];
    }
    $org[$product["member_display_name"]]['payment'] = $product["p_payment"]; //where $product['p_payment'] is a string like '000-111-222'

    return (!empty($org))? $org : array(); 
}

foreach(getVendors() as $vendor => $prods) {
    echo "<li>Vendor Name : {$vendor} </li>";
    if (isset($prods['product'])) echo "<li>".implode("</li><li>",$prods['product'])."</li>";
    if (isset($prods['payment'])) echo "<li>Payment to Vendor : ".$prods['payment']."</li>";
}
```

I'm answering & typing above my head.. hoping you get the general idea.

Comment: I'll try this, Thank you so much.